# Google Analytics Tracking Error - Unrecognized Positional Argument pageview & Tracking script already loaded. Abandoning initialization

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to solve some of my code issues with google debugger but still I can't get it...

Warning 1: Tracking script already loaded. Abandoning initialization.

Warning 2: Unrecognized positional argument: pageview

Warning 3: Running analytics_debug.js. This script is intended for testing and debugging only.

Error 1: extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'frameUrl' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://kcahibnffhnnjcedflmchmokndkjnhpg/everypage.js:1230:40

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
    {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})
    (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    setTimeout("ga('send','event','jdcom','20s')",20000);
    ga('create', 'UA-X-X', 'auto', 'send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the error messages you are seeing. For one thing you are trying to send an event before your tracking object is even created. You need to invert the order - create then send.

Comment: I fixed the one you mentioned but still can't see the effect. Also, I included the error/warning messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Warning 1: Tracking script already loaded. Abandoning initialization.

GA tells you it won't load analytics.js a second time. Not an issue (happens presumably because you load the debugging library via an extension, see below).

> Warning 2: Unrecognized positional argument: pageview

A positional argument is one that relies on the exact position in the arguments passed to the function (as opposed to keyword arguments which are key=value pairs at an arbitrary position in the argument chain).

You are conflating the create and send calls; As far as I know this will not work,  "send" will be used as cookie domain and the fifth argument is not recognized at all since nor argument is expected at the fifth position.

Try to use separate calls for the tracker creation and the send pageview-call, i.e.:

```
 ga('create', 'UA-X-X', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview')
```

The first call will create the tracker, the second one will track the pageview (you do not even need this if all you want are events, but you might get strange reports).

> Warning 3: Running analytics_debug.js. This script is intended for
>   testing and debugging only.

You are running a debugger extension that replaces the default analytics.js with a library that contains debugging functions.

This is not an issue. GA reminds you that you should not use that library in production (which you won't, since it'S probably loaded from an extension, not in the page code).

> Error 1: extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event
>   handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'frameUrl' of
>   undefined at
>   chrome-extension://kcahibnffhnnjcedflmchmokndkjnhpg/everypage.js:1230:40

This is an unrelated security warning from chrome, the browser is unhappy with something an extension is doing. Some extension don't like the browser console while otherwise working fine.

Comment: Should I remove the "pageview" argument?

Comment: @Jim, move it to it's own ga call. I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative response!
Now everything works as expected.
With regards to error No1, I think is AdBlock...

Thanx again!